# my output of link list is not correct?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKyn5.png)[In my link list program I have a problem in output.when second time the compiler ask my choice then its not accept my choice directly output is appears where the problem I can't get it.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faWxS.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your full code.  Posting a link to a picture of part of your code means that (a) this question is only useful for as long as that link remains valid, (b) we can't see all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering data for the previous `scanf`? This newline character is consumed by the `scanf` with a `%c`.

You have to change

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
fflush(stdin);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

so that the `scanf` will skip the newline character left over by the previous `scanf`. The space before `%c` is a whitespace character and whitespace characters in the format string of `scanf` tells `scanf` to scan and discard any number of whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character.

And `fflush(stdin);` is undefined as per the C standard although some implementations define its behavior. Basically, you should avoid it to increase portability.

Comment: I need to enter the program ask my choice yes or no . if i remove fflush(stdin) then compiler does not ask my choice.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Try it first.

Comment: now it can't recived data only asking yes or no?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What's your input, output and expected output? Copy-paste the code here instead of posting images.

Comment: problem is solved thanks...